# My wireless mouse is not working after reboot on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, usb, reboot

If I reboot my computer with the bluetooth micro-receiver of my mouse pluged in a USB, when it boots it doesn't recognise my mouse. (Before the reboot the mouse was working properly)

If I shutdown the laptop and boot it again (without unpluging the reciever), it recognises the mouse properly.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 beta 2 64bit with the latest package updates till today, on a lenovo g510 laptop.

> Mouse: LOGITECH M185 WIRELESS MOUSE
>  Laptop: Lenovo G510 i7
>   4700MQ, 8GB RAM, 128GB SSD Samsung Evo 840.

```
lsb_release -rd
Description:    Ubuntu Trusty Tahr (development branch)
Release:    14.04

$uname -r
3.13.0-19-generic
```

- [dmesg after reboot](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7169569/)
- [dmesg after shutdown and reboot](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7169571/)
- [lspci after reboot](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7169573/)
- [lspci after shutdown and reboot](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7169575/)
- [lsusb after  reboot](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7169580/)
- [lsusb after shutdown and reboot](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7169583/)

As you can see in the two lsusb files, it is not only my mouse not recognised but no other USB device.

I don't know in which package to file a bug report in launchpad, so I'm refering to you.

Comment: To those who set the question off-topic. I respect your decision, however as you can see at the bottom of my question I mention "I don't know in which package to file a bug report in launchpad, so I'm refering to you.". Where else could I get such information. As you can see the answer I got from @Moga helped spot the faulty package. Based on the help center's guidelines you are right but what else could I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had many issues with 3.13 kernel. such as VMWare workstation kernel issues.
I recommend that you try the previous kernel 3.12X and see if that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I didn't try the previous kernel but the latest, kernel 3.14.0 rc8. My problem is solved now. However, trying to boot from that kernel, I found an other bug. I couldn't access the grub. To do so I've install boot-repair and click on recomended fixes. The process finished with errors (http://paste.ubuntu.com/7173127/) but it did actually worked. I was able to access grub properly and select the latest kernel. Since then my mouse works flawlessly. So now I know that I should file a bug report in linux-kernel package.